# Uploaded file at azure is 0 bites

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to upload image to azure blob storage. It succeeded but, My uploaded image appears 0 bites in my azure blob storage.

```
var fs = require('fs');

const fileUpload = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.files.file)
  var blobSvc = azure.createBlobService();
  var file = req.files.file.tempFilePath;
  var stream = fs.createReadStream(file)
  var dataLength = 0;
  // using a readStream that we created already
  stream
    .on('data', function (chunk) {
      dataLength += chunk.length;
    })
    .on('end', function () {
      console.log('The length was:', dataLength);
    });

  blobSvc.createBlockBlobFromStream("image", req.files.file.name, stream, dataLength, function (error, result, response) {
    if (!error) {
      console.log('ok Blob uploaded')
      console.log(result)
      console.log(response)
    } else {
      console.log(error)
    }

  })
}


module.exports = fileUpload
```

This is how, my req.files.file obj received from frontend.

```
file: {
    name: 'test.png',
    data: <Buffer >,
    size: 184332,
    encoding: '7bit',
    tempFilePath: '/tmp/tmp-1-1585187683435',
    truncated: false,
    mimetype: 'image/png',
    md5: 'b8532c65a5c1ba95bbe89b6589b94a6c',
    mv: [Function: mv]
  }
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the frontend code please?

Comment: Could you please provide the entire upload process?

Comment: @GauravMantri the was not related to frontend , so I did not posted here.

Comment: The reason I asked for frontend code is because there may be other ways to solve the problem you're facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to specify the length, you could try [createWriteStreamToBlockBlob](https://azure.github.io/azure-storage-node/BlobService.html#createWriteStreamToBlockBlob).

The code will look like this:

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');
var blobService = azure.createBlobService();
var stream = fs.createReadStream(fileNameTarget).pipe(blobService.createWriteStreamToBlockBlob(containerName, blobName, { blockIdPrefix: 'block' }));
```

Comment: This solutions worked, but still few images are 0 bites. I am able to see it in approx 40%